# TCPDF - Table split on multiple page and show page wise total

Tags: php, tcpdf

I want to Show table in tcpdf using writehtml or writehtmlcell. Table may have 1000 of row. It will show on multiple page. Till this point I have achieved but at the same time I want to show page wise total of quantity column.

```
$loc_body = "<table>
<tr><td>Item Name</td><td>Qty</td></tr>
<tr><td>ABC</td><td>12</td></tr>
<tr><td>PQR</td><td>15</td></tr>
.
.
.
.
.
.
</table>";

$pdf->writeHTML(0,148,5,70, $loc_body,0);
```

What will be step I should take?

Comment: I don't think this is possible ... you will have to check how many rows can fit on one page and then split your table accordingly.